# How to run powershell script from CMD, so that *.PS1 would properly convert HEX values to decimal

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have simple script to detect GPU memory from regedit.

```
$mem_devid = get-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\????" -Name  HardwareInformation.AdapterString, MatchingDeviceId, HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize

$GPU_Info = Get-CIMInstance Win32_VideoController

foreach ($i in $GPU_Info.PNPDeviceID) {

$gpu_id_tmp = $i -Split "&"
$gpu_id = $gpu_id_tmp[1]

$current_gpu = $mem_devid | where { $_ -match $gpu_id }

$gpu_name = $current_gpu."HardwareInformation.AdapterString"

IF ($gpu_mem -lt 1) {
$gpu_mem = "N/A or DVMT"
} ELSE {
$gpu_mem = $current_gpu."HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize"/1048576
}

Write-Host $gpu_name
Write-Host $gpu_mem
}
```

It works fine in ISE. The output in my case is:

```
GeForce GT 710
2048
```

But if I call above script from cmd

```
powershell -file "D:\PS-script\gpi_id.ps1"
```

The output is

```
GeForce GT 710
N/A or DVMT
```

No matter if I run as Admin or not. I guess the problem is that when called from CMD powershell can not convert "HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize" (which stored in hex format) to decimal.

Can I run powershell script from CMD so that it would be capable to convert hex value to decimal properly? Or solve the problem otherwise.

Comment: `$gpu_mem` is not defined and probably retrieved from a higher scope (host prompt) in the ISE.

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me. I had wrong logic. IF statment before the variable which it takes for comparison. Proper code below

```
$mem_devid = get-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\????" -Name  HardwareInformation.AdapterString, MatchingDeviceId, HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize

$GPU_Info = Get-CIMInstance Win32_VideoController

foreach ($i in $GPU_Info.PNPDeviceID) {

$gpu_id_tmp = $i -Split "&"
$gpu_id = $gpu_id_tmp[1]

$current_gpu = $mem_devid | where { $_ -match $gpu_id }

$gpu_name = $current_gpu."HardwareInformation.AdapterString"
$gpu_mem = $current_gpu."HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize"

IF ($gpu_mem -lt 1) {
$gpu_mem = "N/A or DVMT"
} ELSE {
$gpu_mem_fnl = $gpu_mem/1048576
}

Write-Host $gpu_name
Write-Host $gpu_mem_fnl
}
```